# How do I split my web application?

Tags: javascript, css, architecture, package, single-page-application

We create a Single Page Application. Say this is ProjectA.

We then decided, due to good fortune, to make ProjectB.

90% of ProjectA and ProjectB are the same.

This is saying to me that we need `ProjectCore` `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`.  The latter 2 must use the first as a dependency.

What muddies the water is that, it is not just JavaScript.  The Designer said "I am going to have your problem but with CSS!".  So I mean, if the `ProjectCore` has a `ConfirmationModalView`, then the CSS which styles that view should travel with it.

How do you handle this? Is this what WebPack and their ilk are for?  What common solutions exist for resolving this problem?

"Copy and Paste all the Code from A into B then maintain both" is getting votes but this is lame. Although I can't say I can offer a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into Git and version control. BUT... You could have one main JS and CSS file for the stuff that is not changing.

You can then add smaller, separate JS files, for which have specific functions, for `Project A` and `Project B` individually (Note if you include below the "main JS", all the global functions and variables will be available for this JS file to use, kind of a bonus if need be).

You can then use `@import url("base.css");` at the top of your two different, smaller CSS files to "combine the main CSS with new, specific CSS for "that" page only.

Answer (score 0):

you need use MVC ...
your Model are the same.. becouse it is your object manager Server Side.
your View is diferente becouse you have a diferent User Interface.

and you can dev Controller as you needed... in javascript ajax to comunicate with sever by event user... Controller php can manajer default informacion. DB Connection, Encription... ETC.

you can upload static to a server as CSS and JS and core proyect PHP to the server side...

You can add Controller 1, 2, 3 or View 1, 2, 3 depending on the project an you have a core View and core Controller.

[image]

Comment: Not even close to relevant. Model–view–controller (MVC) is a software architect pattern for implementation of UI, not close to version control at all.

Comment: Version Control demands that all your applications are updated to the latest version to avoid errors in code ... this can cause all equal. if you are looking for a different interface for managing web application must use MVC ... Use the model and controller as version control, but your "view" can adjust as needed. also he is talking about: "Copy and Paste all the code from A into B then a Maintain both" this means that no project has a multi defined architecture. and there is nothing better to implement a model of programming just in time.

Comment: Versioning, A/B Testing - Used the same here. Trying to use MVC, especially if you don't start with MVC in mind, would screw you up. Sure you could have many controllers, sure you can have one view, but what if the views need to be different (A/B Testing), you're broken. Might as well make two full projects at that point right?

Comment: not necessarily ... the idea of version control is to lift collaboratively code has nothing to do with bringing 1 2 3 Different projects ... MVC is much more scalable version control in this regard. you may have: a JS, CSS and PHP core ... and have at the same time 2 3 4 projects A, B, C that refer to the same core with different user interfaces, events and data. This is to discussed many times. Version control is for linear development. MVC and other architectures, is to develop multiple applications and module assembly (Framework).

Comment: Version - "a particular form of something differing in certain respects from an earlier form or **other forms** of the same type of thing."

Agree to disagree. For as simple as this is, you have made it unbearable. This kid is not developing his own Framework, might want to reel in your scope from saving the world to saving this kids project.

Comment: if you see he is talking about dependency ... he have 1 project that have some file repeated in the second ... he need explain most repeated file as a core file as dependency for the other two ... this treat as architecture... if he have some forms with little diferent he need assembly it by needed from UI Side... but if JS and CSS is repeated as a base design, he need make sure that css and JS file is a part of core design... and what he need personalize for every project.. MVC help to handle this Controll version not.